# Gnome "auto-move windows"-extension does not show all applications

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, window-management, workspaces

I really love the extension "auto-move windows", but it is rather limited: the "Add Rule" Button shows a list which only contains certain applications -- those that installed through apt, I suppose. (But then, why whould System Monitor be missing then?)

What I want is to add any application I made a .desktop file for to that list. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You might be better off opening a bug with the developer or creating a feature request.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there already is a solution to this somehow before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gtk application chooser used by the extension's settings used to exclude applications that do not support opening files, i.e. have no [URI/file parameter](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) in the `Exec` key of their .desktop file. [This issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789327) got fixed and [the fix](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?h=gtk-3-22&id=5ad9ecaff050b3417d330ea9d229679ec2511217) is included in [gtk+ 3.22.25](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/NEWS?h=3.22.25#n54) and newer.

Comment: I switched to Arch and now have the latest version and it indeed shows every program in the list now. I wonder how long I will still have to wait until my Debian Laptop gets it...

Answer (score 1):

Place the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/`. You should be able to find it in the application chooser for Auto Move Windows.

Comment: I have an eclipse.desktop file in that exact folder and the application does not show up in that list

Comment: @piegames Strange! It works for me, extension version 34.

Comment: @pmpsky How do I check my extension's version?

Comment: @piegames Go to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` (if the extension is installed locally). Look for the folder associated to the extension and open it. Open the `metadata.js` file, the version should be written in it.